# How to add a cookie to a request when the cookie is protected against xss (js)

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, jwt

I have a server where I send a jwt cookie to the user's browser after login and I put the setting of "httpOnly: true" to ensure against XSS.
Now I want to send a request to the server from the client side how do I send the jwt to the server if I can't access it on the client side?
(I'm using axios and Java Script)

This is how I would do it if "httpOnly: true" was not set.
But because it is set then the jwt is undefined:

```
const jwt = Cookies.get('jwt')

axios.get('/Any address', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: A `httponly` cookie will automatically be send. Unless it's a cross domain request

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie is set, then the web browser would anyway send it in the header, right?

Is that not happening? If not, please check if the cookie(s) are set properly and verify it on the client, whichever client you are using

Comment: You know what you're right, I've seen someone do it differently and it confused me.
You set me back. Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Do mark it as an answer then, please :-)